# Difference between BigQuery Audit logs and Job log

Tags: google-bigquery, audit-logging

I cannot understand if there is a principle difference between Audit logs and Job log in BQ in relation to my search. If i want to see by whom, when and which query was executed. As far as I undertand I can find this information in both sources and I cannot understand if audit log contains more?

Answer (score 0):

> If i want to see by whom, when and which query was executed

You are correct, if you want these details audit logs is the way to go. While Job logs gives information of logs about jobs ( job type, the job state, and the user who created the job.).

For more details information you might want to visit Google's documentation about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/introduction-audit-workloads).

Comment: but query is a job? so in job logs i see the same as in audit? and even more to that, if i see correctly in audit logs only servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent column is not empty (there are so many columns, that i couldn't go through all of them)